# C - malloc doesn't allocate the requested memory

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I've made a struct, and I wanted to make an array of that struct, I tried allocating memory using `malloc()` but it doesn't seem to allocate the requested memory.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Players{
    int level_;
    char name_[15];
    float progress_;
    float health_;
} player;

int main()
{
    player *n =  malloc(2 * sizeof(player));
    printf("%d \n", sizeof(n));

    free(n);

    return 0;
}
```

the allocated memory is 8, instead of 56.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `sizeof(n)` - `n` is a *pointer*.

Comment: `n` is a pointer, so you are printing the size of a pointer.  Also, sizes should be printed with `%zu`

Comment: Ah, so you are running under a 64-bit system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004704/c-malloc-and-array-length